# CSS4 родительский селектор

Tags: css

Привет.
Кто-то тестировал новые родительские селекторы?
Никак не могу найти поддержку по браузерам.

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="Name"/>
    <span class="help hide">Your name sir</span>
</div>

.input-wrap! .help > input[type=text]:focus { display: block; }
```

Comment: Тут можно проверить ваш браузер: http://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/

Comment: Благодарен

Comment: ООООО, в CSS4 такое будет? :333333

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, не знаю ссылок на авторитетные источники, но пока родительские селекторы в текущих версиях браузеров не поддерживаются.

Comment: Благодарен за инфу!